# Croatian diacritic signs MySQL DB - like clause

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL db, db engine InnoDB, collation set to utf8-utf8_general_ci (also tried utf8_unicode_ci). I would like db to treat equaly č and c, ž and z, ć and c, š and s, đ and d.
E.g,

`table1`

```
-------------
id  | name
-------------
1   | mačka
2   | đemper
-------------
```

if I run query: 
`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE '%mac%'` 
or 
`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE '%mač%'`
I will get the result:

```
-------------
id  | name
-------------
1   | mačka
```

Which is OK, that is exactly what I want.  
But if run query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE '%de%'
```

I get zero results.

And if I run query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE '%đe%'
```

I will get:

```
-------------
id  | name
-------------
2   | đemper
```

This is not behaviour that i would want nor expect. I would like that both (last two queries) returned:

```
-------------
id  | name
-------------
2   | đemper
```

How can I accomplish this? 
Any kind of help is appreciated, thanks in advance :) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done without the use of regular expressions, as there is no collation in MySQL that considers `đ` equivalent to `d`.

Comment: Thank you both for fast reply! That clarified a lot of things for me. @IgnacioVazquezAbrams can you explain a little bit more about the use of regular expressions?

Comment: I think you ment something like this: SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE name rlike '[dđ]e.' It helps! Tnx! :)

Comment: I just don't know why is that if I have 'đemper' and 'dem' records in table1 and run query: SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE name rlike '.[dđ]e.' it only returns 'đemper', and if I run SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE name rlike '[dđ]e.' it returns both ('dem' and 'đemper')?

Answer (score 0):

The collation you are using determines things like this -- what characters are considered 'equal', and what order they should sort in. But first off, you need to know what encoding your table is using.

The command `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table1'\G` should show you that. That will help you determine the collation you need to use.

If it's Unicode (UTF8, e.g.), then you need to set a Unicode collation. There doesn't appear to be one built-in to MySQL for Croatian. You can check the [MySQL Character Set manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-unicode-sets.html) to see if anything there is going to be 'close enough'.

If it's iso-latin-2 (iso-8859-2), then you can use 'latin2_croatian_ci' collation.

If it's CP-1250, then there is also a 'cp1250_croatian_ci' collation.

The non-unicode collations are in the manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-ce-sets.html).

**EDIT**
As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams correctly points out, none of the MySQL collations consider 'đ' to be equivalent to 'd'. ([Reference for MySQL collations](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/))

If you are really eager to put a lot of time into this, you can also read up on [how to install your own custom collation](http://forge.mysql.com/w/images/b/b7/HowToAddACollation.pdf)